# How do I kill a process after detaching it from bash?

Tags: bash, process, kill, job-control

I have multiple scripts that detach a process from bash using `nohup` and `&>/dev/null &`. My question is, how do I kill the process after completely detaching it from bash. using `killall` or `pidof ScriptName` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nohup` should only affect the hangup signal. So `kill` should still work normally. Maybe you are using the wrong pid or process name; compare with `pstree -p` or `ps -ef`.

If you still suspect `nohup`, maybe you could try `disown` instead.

```
$ sleep 1000 &
$ jobs -p
13561
$ disown
$ jobs -p
$ pidof sleep
13561
$ kill 13561
$ pidof sleep
$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used `nohup`, you can't kill them. The `nohup` command specifically prevents those processes from receiving the kill signals. If you simply used `&`, you can kill them by sending a `kill` or `kill -9` to the PID. Well, you can kill them by rebooting the machine, but that might be a bit more extreme than you really want...

Comment: Closing the terminal still kills the process. Is there any way I can keep that from happening?

Comment: With `nohup`, closing the terminal should not kill the process, it should simply transfer the process's PPID to init. `nohup` is exactly what you should use to prevent that. Alternately, if you want to reconnect to it later, wrap it in a `screen` session.

Comment: nohup does not make the process immune to kill signals, it makes the process ignore a hup signal, you can kill it with `kill <pid>` and it will die like the rest of them.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me rephrase. When just using `&` and not `nohup`, closing the terminal kills the process. I want to disconnect the job from the terminal, but still be able to kill it if I want. Is there a way to do that?